# Intentionally causing high CPU usage

Tags: ios, swift

I have a question that other people usually have a problem with.

I am building an application that measures battery discharge.

My plan is to simulate high CPU usage and then measure the time it takes the battery to drop to a certain level.

How can I cause high CPU usage on purpose, but without blocking the UI?

Can I do something like this?

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async { [weak self] in
    guard let self = self else { return }
    for _ in 0..<Int.max {
        while self.isRunning {
        }
        break
    }
}
```

Comment: You could try to do some heavy image or video processing on a background thread of a really large file. Look up things like adding filters, adding animations to videos, changing image colors. Here is one idea: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71231680/1619193 - adding colors to an image, just try using an image that maybe is 50 - 100 MB.

Comment: Try to loop billion times and get elapsed time in loop. And repeat until battery level is done. You can also MAUCO this in multiple threads or queues.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. I added example code in my question. @PtitXav Can you confirm for me if it fits? At least the example shows a utilization of 100% without a memory leak. Thanks :)

Comment: You could replace the inner while loop by if self.isRunning .  You can also add some geometric operations using cos, sin,… The goal is just to make the processor run.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you want is persistent load on CPU, with number of threads concurrently loading CPU >= number of CPUs.

So something like

```
DispatchQueue.concurrentPerform(iterations: 100) { iteration in
    for _ in 1...10000000 {
        let a = 1 + 1
    }
}
```

Where:

- The `concurrentPerform` with `iterations` set to 100 makes sure we are running in parallel using every available thread. This is overkill of course, would be enough 4 threads to get every CPU busy on quad core, and about 10 threads is what iOS typically allocates at max per process. But 100 simply makes ruee it really happens)
- The `1...10000000` makes loop really really long
- The `let a = 1 + 1` gives CPU something to do.

On my iPhone 8 simulator running this code created a picture like this (stopped it after about 30 sec):
[image]

**Careful though! You may overheat your device**

Comment: You should check a variable on every iteration (or every n iterations) to know when you're "done", to stop the load